# PHP API FROM ANDROID VOLLEY

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am currently studying Volley. but I keep getting "No Client Connection" from my android I try to debug it with html. seems to be working. How do you handle API POST request. I try to read the documentation of volley. Still, I'm stuck

this is my Android codes in user registration.

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText Name,Username,Password,Email;
    Button register;
    private String name,username,password,email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        Name = findViewById(R.id.register_fullname);
        Username = findViewById(R.id.register_username);
        Password = findViewById(R.id.register_password);
        Email = findViewById(R.id.register_email);
        register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);



        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               name = Name.getText().toString();
               email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
               password = Password.getText().toString().trim();
               username = Username.getText().toString().trim();

                if(name.isEmpty()){
                    message("Fill all fileds");
                }else{
                    Reigster();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

/// Register Method below

```
    private void Reigster(){
        name = Name.getText().toString();
        email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
        password = Password.getText().toString().trim();
        username = Username.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Urls.REGISTER_URL,
                response -> message("Success"),
                error -> message("Erro-r")){
            @Nullable
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name",name);
                params.put("username",username);
                params.put("password",password);
                params.put("email",email);
                return params;
            }
        };

       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Registration.this);
       requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    public void message(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

here is my code in php. I used "isset()" just to get rid of the message "Unknown Variable"

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(`firstname`,`lastname`,`username`,`password`) VALUES(,'$firstname','$lastname','$username','$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(!$result){
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is Register method?

Comment: here is the register metheod   "private void Reigster() " just below after the call of the method

Comment: Ok. So what's not working? The Java part seems good. But your php doesn't return anything. Where does $_POST['id'] come from?

Comment: You need to return a response than in your Java code you'll catch it and proceed.

Comment: First, return a proper success or failure response from your server, then in your volley error response, properly decode a response, not just message("Erro-r"), this helps you to get the proper error message